# Symlink to bash file

Tags: linux

I'm trying to symlink a `roo.sh` file to `/usr/local/bin` so I can use the `roo` command directly but I'm having some troubles.

```
$ ls
roo.sh
$ ln -s roo.sh /usr/local/bin/roo
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/roo
$ roo
command not found
$ bash /usr/local/bin/roo
No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ln -s roo.sh /usr/local/bin/roo` would create a symlink to a file `roo.sh` in the same directory (`/usr/local/bin/roo` --> `/usr/local/bin/roo.sh`) - you can verify this by using `ls -l /usr/local/bin/roo`.

To avoid this, use the full path to `roo.sh` when creating the symlink:

`ln -s /path/to/roo.sh /usr/local/bin/roo`

Answer (score -1):

Do you have anough privileges to create /usr/local/bin/roo ?

Does your script start with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

?

Try to use sudo, if it's installed or invoke this commands by root user.